# Kafka consumer behavior when one consumer goes down/crash

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, jvm-crash

My topics has 115 partition and around 130 consumers. I expect 115 consumers in active state (1 to 1 assignment) and the remaining 15 consumers in idle state.

A few times, I observed high memory and JVM in hung state due to which rebalancing is triggered. However, I am unsure if this causes the full rebalancing (i.e., healthy node assignments also gets changed ??) or only the dead node's assigned partitions get assigned to one of the idle nodes ?

Also, in case of restart of the application (mine is a distributed 1 thread/consumer per JVM), how does the rebalance behave ? As the nodes are starting one by one (rolling restart), will the rebalance happen 115 times (ie., every time a new consumer joins the group) or is some threshold/wait applied before kick starting the rebalance (to ensure all healthy nodes join the application)?

Answer (score 2):

Consumer rebalance is triggered anytime a Kafka consumer with the same group ID joins the group or leaves.  Leaving the consumer group can be done explicitly by closing a consumer connection, or by timeout if the JVM or server crashed.

So in your case, yes, a rolling restart of the consumers would trigger 115 consumer rebalances.  There is no "threshold" or "wait period" before starting a rebalance in Kafka.

Comment: Thanks @mjuarez. What happens in case of bulk restart. Practically, all the 115 consumers shall ping/enroll broker at 115 different timestamps. Will broker trigger them 115 times or wait for some specified time (it make sense actually !!) before kicking in rebalance.

Comment: *There is no "threshold" or "wait period" before starting a rebalance* -- Well, there is `session.timeout.ms` & `heartbeat.interval.ms`

Answer (score 0):

By default [RangeAssignor.java](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RangeAssignor.html) - is used which may cause that even healthy consumers get different partitions assigned to them over and over again when something happens with other node. It may also mean that partition will be taken from healthy consumer. You may tweak that so it uses different implementations of `PartitionAssignor` interface - for example [StickyAssignor.java](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/StickyAssignor.html)
"*one advantage of the sticky assignor is that, in general, it reduces the number of partitions that actually move from one consumer to another during a reassignment*".

I would also recommend reading https://medium.com/@anyili0928/what-i-have-learned-from-kafka-partition-assignment-strategy-799fdf15d3ab if you want some deep dive how does it work undearneath

Comment: Thanks @freakman for pointing to StickyAssignor. I think this would still trigger rebalancing. I am looking for a way by which the healthy consumers doesn't even get impacted by rogue consumers triggering rebalancing and healthy consumers continue as is.. Only the affected partitions (due to rogue) could be reassigned to a few other healthy nodes (or idle nodes) and keep the rogue out of the consumer group (or mark idle)